# Passing path string to a jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I have a  string file path that needs to be passed to jquery function this how it looks."3rd parameter on function `viewDocument(extension,filename,filepath)`"

```
<div onclick="viewDocument(doc,APPLICATION FOR POSITION OF HOW2 STUDENT LEADER,/Uploads/2018/Applicant_s219193029/documents/)" class="document info">         
  <div class="document-body">            
    <i class="fa fa-file-word-o text-info"></i>         
  </div>         
  <div class="document-footer">            
    <span class="document-name">APPLICATION FOR POSITION OF HOW2 STUDENT LEADER.doc </span>           <span class="document-description"> 53KB </span>         
  </div>     
</div>
```

I have been trying to modify with no luck.

Comment: I'd imagine that both the second and third parameters are supposed to be *strings*. Try wrapping them with single quotes instead: `viewDocument(doc,'APPLICATION FOR POSITION OF HOW2 STUDENT LEADER','/Uploads/2018/Applicant_s219193029/documents/')`

Comment: Yes, thanks guys its working, I forgot to mention the viewDocument() is in the js, but yes I was missing the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap them in Single Quotes `'` in this case as the onclick  function is surrounded with Double Quotes `"`

> onclick= " viewDocument('doc','APPLICATION FOR POSITION OF HOW2 STUDENT
>   LEADER','/Uploads/2018/Applicant_s219193029/documents/') "

Alternatively, with Double Quotes `"` if the function is wrapped with Single Quotes `'`

> onclick= ' viewDocument("doc","APPLICATION FOR POSITION OF HOW2 STUDENT
>   LEADER","/Uploads/2018/Applicant_s219193029/documents/") '

```js
function viewDocument(extension,filename,filepath)
{
console.log(filepath);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="viewDocument('doc','APPLICATION FOR POSITION OF HOW2 STUDENT LEADER','/Uploads/2018/Applicant_s219193029/documents/')" class="document info">         
  <div class="document-body">            
    <i class="fa fa-file-word-o text-info"></i>         
  </div>         
  <div class="document-footer">            
    <span class="document-name">APPLICATION FOR POSITION OF HOW2 STUDENT LEADER.doc </span>           <span class="document-description"> 53KB </span>         
  </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: In your given example, it should be single quotes only, as double quotes would cut the onclick short. As OP may be new to the subject, it could be important to mention this.

Comment: @cmprogram, ya maybe, I've described it a bit